# How to scale the original anatomical image to the size I want

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have an anatomical.mat file. Its content shows as follows:

```
    flip_angle: 0
            tr: 1000
            te: 0
            ti: 0
      vox2ras0: [4x4 double]
       volsize: [256 124 256]
        height: 256
         width: 124
         depth: 256
       nframes: 1
       vox2ras: [4x4 double]
       nvoxels: 8126464
         xsize: 1.2000
         ysize: 0.9375
         zsize: 0.9375
           x_r: 1
           x_a: 0
           x_s: 0
           y_r: 0
           y_a: 1
           y_s: 0
           z_r: 0
           z_a: 0
           z_s: 1
           c_r: 74.4000
           c_a: 120
           c_s: 120
      vox2ras1: [4x4 double]
           Mdc: [3x3 double]
        volres: [1.2000 0.9375 0.9375]
    tkrvox2ras: [4x4 double]
```

And I have another fMRI.mat file, which comes from the same subject as the anantomical.mat. The content of fMRI.mat shows as follows:

```
flip_angle: 0
        tr: 2500
        te: 0
        ti: 0
  vox2ras0: [4x4 double]
   volsize: [64 40 64]
    height: 64
     width: 40
     depth: 64
   nframes: 1452
   vox2ras: [4x4 double]
   nvoxels: 163840
     xsize: 3.5000
     ysize: 3.7500
     zsize: 3.7500
       x_r: 1
       x_a: 0
       x_s: 0
       y_r: 0
       y_a: 1
       y_s: 0
       z_r: 0
       z_a: 0
       z_s: 1
       c_r: 70
       c_a: 120
       c_s: 120
  vox2ras1: [4x4 double]
       Mdc: [3x3 double]
    volres: [3.5000 3.7500 3.7500]
tkrvox2ras: [4x4 double]
```

My question is how can I convert the anatomical size: 256*124*256 to the size of the fMRI data 64*40*64. Note: they come from the same subject, I mean from the same person. Anyone can help me? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't understand the question, what output is expected?

Comment: I want to draw the fMRI data 3D matrix (get rid of the time dimension) over the anatomical data 3-D matrix, but their size does not match.

Comment: for the anatomical matrix size is 256*124*256, but the fMRI matrix size is 64*40*64. but they both comes from the same subject, the same person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any data value except setting.

But if you want to convert a 3D meshgrid, use [`interp3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp3.html) to fill out the data points.

There must be grid point values 3D location value and corresponding value at the point. Make sure to change the 3D location to have the same size as the target.

Comment: The fMRI matrix is 64*40*64, and for each point there is a value

Comment: I want to know how to convert the 256*124*256 anatomical matrix to 64*40*64,so that I can overlay the fMRI matrix onto the anatomical matrix.

Comment: christopher,I am not quite get your idea